# IIS PHP Configuration

Tags: php, cakephp, iis-7

I am working on a project for a client that uses cakePHP and I'm having a hard time getting it to run on my cluster.  The app connects to the DB just fine, however keeps displaying php code instead of parsing it.

Example

```
link('Download a Catalogue',array('controller'=>'catalogues','action'=>'index', 'admin'=>false),array('class'=>'aaa'))?>
```

Does anyone have any ideas?  My suspicion was that this line of code does not contain a ';' at the end.  That said, this code works totally find on his unix server.  Is there a way to override IIS to not require a ';' at the end of a line?

Comment: did you add the type handler for `.php` files to use the PHP IIS dll?

Comment: Yes.  It actually parses some of the code.  It is very strange.  It looks like the link and image functions are a part of an 'ajax.php' file within the cakePHP library.  I don't see this file 'required' anywhere.  Maybe that's my issue?  I have no experience with cakePHP, I try to avoid PHP at all costs...

Comment: Seems that this issue is related to the URL Rewriting that cakePHP requires.  I added a few different rules and things have started to work a little better, still not parsing all code though.  I'll upload the rules when I have the complete list.

Comment: You might have missing `<?php` that denotes the start of your PHP code. `?>` denotes the end of PHP snippets.

Answer (score 0):

I feel dumb now...  The previous developer used short hand PHP tags .  Enabled short hand in the PHP.INI and bam.

Thanks guys.